# AngularJs: Find links with initial 'www' in the text and turns them into html links

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular [linky](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky) to find links in the text and convert them to url. 
But linky doesn't support URL like following:

```
www.abc.com
abc.xyz
```

is there any other way to support those links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linky` filter [already supports](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/ngSanitize/filter/linky.js#L107) www.abc.com-like addresses.

And developing regexps by yourself to support `abc.xyz` is too complex and thankless job to do it alone. I would suggest to use mature third-party library for that, like [Autolinker](https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js) is.

[Here is a simple module](http://plnkr.co/edit/cGIYxxyKh3brB6sdEGVn?p=preview) that may help to configure (with options [supported by Autolinker](https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js#options)) and wrap it into Angular filter

```
angular.module('linkier', ['ngSanitize'])
.constant('linkierConfig', {})
.filter('linkier', ['$window', '$sanitize', 'linkierConfig', 
  function ($window, $sanitize, linkierConfig) {
  return function (input, config) {
    if (!angular.isString(input))
      return input;

    config = angular.extend({}, linkierConfig, angular.isObject(config) ? config : {});
    return $sanitize($window.Autolinker.link(input, config));
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Finds links in text input and turns them into html links. Supports
>   http/https/ftp/mailto and plain email address links.

So it seems that it doesn't. You should create your own filter to solve this problem. Here's a template to get you started.

```
angular
    .module('app.filters')
        .filter('urlLink', urlLink);

function urlLink() {
    return function(value) {
        var result = '';
        // ... logic ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

[What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: I already told linky doesn't support and also ask for any other way. You gave me the way to create my own filter. But as Linky, I also need to add a hyperlink DOM inside my scope. Can you please elaborate this one?

Comment: I assumed you are interested in parsing a certain binding inside your view, e.g. ``{{ text }}``. A filter is a function which receives parameters and returns a result. So ``{{ foo(text) }}`` is equivalent to ``{{ text | foo }}`` if you make ``foo`` a filter. So just write your own filter which will parse the text (with regular expressions, see link I added) and replace the matches in the regular expressions (e.g. ``$1``) with ``<a href="$1">$1</a>``. So when you find ``www.url.com`` you will turn it with regex into ``<a href="www.url.com">www.url.com</a>``.